# Fetching data from MYSQL to Dropdown list

Tags: php

I'm trying to populate my dropdown list from some values I have stored in my database. So far the code is working fine the database connection is fine and when i execute the php file it shows the dropdown with the number of entries in the database but all the options are empty it just shows a blank space instead of the name in the database.

This is the code

```
     <?php
     require "db_con.php";

     $table = "doctors";

     $stmt=$dbcon->prepare("SELECT Name FROM $table");
     $stmt->execute();

     $data=$stmt->fetchAll();


     echo "<select name='name'>";
     foreach ($data as $row):
         echo '<option><?=$row["Name"]?></option>';
      endforeach;

     echo "</select>";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that `"Name"` is the correct name of the column whose data you seek?  When do you get on screen if you do `print_r($row)`?

Comment: missing value  echo '<option value="<?=$row["Name"]?>"><?=$row["Name"]?></option>';

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is a problem, so try this:

```
echo "<option>".$row["Name"]."</option>";
```

Comment: Thanks figured this out a couple of minutes after posting the question but thank you very much